# Infinite torsion CAT(0) groups

Tags: group-theory, metric-spaces, geometric-group-theory, open-problem

Do all infinite CAT(0) groups contain a $\mathbb{Z}$ subgroup? I am aware that this has been established for hyperbolic groups, and similar questions have appeared on open questions lists for CAT(0) groups, namely [here](http://www.math.utah.edu/~bestvina/eprints/questions.pdf). However, typically this is worded as 'Does there exist an infinite torsion subgroup of a CAT(0) group' or 'is there a infinite torsion group which acts properly discontinuously on a CAT(0) space.' Obviously subgroups can be fairly distorted and cocompactness is a strong condition. Does anyone know if this is an established fact, or is this still an open question?

For the sake of clarity I am defining $G$ to be CAT(0) if it acts properly discontinuously and cocompactly on a proper CAT(0) space.

Comment: There exist infinite torsion groups acting properly discontinuously on a CAT(0) space. See for instance Example II.7.11 in Haefliger and Bridson's book, where the authors construct, for every increasing sequence $G_0 \subset G_1 \subset \cdots$ of finite groups, a proper action of $\lim G_n$ on a metric simplicial tree.

Comment: This is not an answer, but for sure there's no known counterexample since this would be a finitely presented infinite torsion group and the existence of such group is a famous open problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is proven by Swenson in

E. Swenson, A cut point theorem for CAT(0) groups, J. Differential Geom. 53
(1999), no. 2, 327–358.

that each infinite CAT(0) group contains an infinite order element.